# I have a NaN value every time I sum a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a button to add a kiss counter, but I'm getting a `NaN` value and I don't know how to solve it. Can you guys please help me?

I'm saving the values in `LocalStorage` and I'm getting the values of the DOM with jQuery. This is what im doing to save the data:

```
<h1>Due: <span id="counter">0</span></h1>
<a id="btn" href="javascript:void(0);">+</a>

var btn = $('#btn').click(function() {
        var valor = $('#counter');        
        valor.text(parseInt(valor) + 1);
        saveData();
    });

function saveData() {
    if (supportsLocalStorage()) {
        var counter = $('#counter').text();
        localStorage.setItem('kisses', counter);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a NaN value everytime I click the plus button.

I have a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/usdjsr40/

Hope you guys can help me with my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse an object so **NaN** and **NaN** + 1 gives **NaN**. So try this:

```
var btn = $('#btn').click(function() {
        var valor = $('#counter');        
        valor.text(parseInt(valor.html().trim()) + 1);
        saveData();
    });

function saveData() {
    if (supportsLocalStorage()) {
        var counter = $('#counter').text();
        localStorage.setItem('kisses', counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a html object to parseInt, thus it's sending NaN.

```
 var valor = $('#counter');
```

Here valor is html element not a string.

Try this:-

```
 var valor = $('#counter').text().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

NaN means Not a Number. You're not loading the data from `$('#counter')` appropriately.

`$('#counter')` is simply the jQuery element object. You're attempting to add the number one to a JavaScript object, rather than a number.

In order to get the value within the element, you need to call it like this:

```
$('#counter').html()
```

Then you can wrap parseInt around it:

```
parseInt( $('#counter').html() )
```

So your first few lines of code should look like:

```
<h1>Due: <span id="counter">0</span></h1>
<a id="btn" href="javascript:void(0);">+</a>

var btn = $('#btn').click(function() {
        var valor = $('#counter').html();     
        valor.text(parseInt(valor) + 1);
        saveData();
    });
```

Comment: `valor.text(parseInt(valor) + 1);`? valor is not a object.